# Backup using dd reformatted disk from ntfs to ext4. Can I recover any of the files?

Tags: filesystems, dd

I accidentally started a backup from `/dev/sda3` my root partition that is formatted as `ext4` to my backup hard drive `dev/sdb2` which was formatted as `NTFS`. I did this using the `dd` command:

```
dd if=dev/sda3 of=/dev/sdb2
```

When I recognized the mistake I canceled the command, but now when I run `lsblk -f` it lists the backup hard drive as `ext4`.

I am also not unable to mount the disk. I receive this error:

```
mount: /media/HD: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2, 
missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Is there anyway to rescue any of the files on the hard drive that may not have been overwritten?

Comment: This is almost an exact duplicate of [Recover file system after overwriting first sectors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/413752/23408), but its answer, while valid, is a bit skimpy.

Comment: [Partially overwrote ```/dev/sda```; can I recover anything?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/148045/23408) has a good answer,  although it’s a bit specific to an ext4 filesystem.

Comment: See also [Data recovery from an accidental format on ext4 partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168704/23408).

Answer (score 0):

Try https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk.  There's a good chance it's available on your Linux distro (I checked Ubuntu, Debian, and CentOS).  I used it to recover files from a reformatted Windows drive for a friend.  (It's mentioned in an answer linked in the quesion's comments, but wasn't the accepted answer for that situation.)  You'll need something to write the recovered files to.

Answer (score 0):

You should first backup the current bad partition to some big external disk

```
dd if=/dev/sdb2 of=/mountpoint/of/bigdisk/backup_of_sdb2.dd
```

then you can test various techniques to try to recover your former sdb2 content.   Use utilities, and revert to the starting point of they failed, using the backed up  file.

One way to do a fix manually could be to also dump that db2 content onto a whole *empty* external drive (to its /dev/sdX, or /dev/sdX1 ?) and then change that partition type to ntfs  (with fdisk) and use a windows to try to fix it? (may recover some lost directory structure)...

And lastly... always have backups of important data (on 2 local separate disks, and one remote location as well in case of robbery or fire...). makes those occurence much less painful to deal with.